# angular: $watch set in a loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I do the following

```
 $scope.product.orders.forEach(function (order) {
    $scope.$watch('order.details.items.length', function (n, o) {
       if (n !== o) {
          //do something
        }
     });
  }, true);
```

where `details` is an object and `items` is an array.

The $watch is triggered once for every orders in the collection, with n and o being undefined.

Then whenever I add an item to the items array, the $watch is not triggered. Why is that ? There is no errors in the log.

note: I know that creating a $watch in a loop is clearly not a good thing performance-wise, it's a workaround for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the first parameter of $scope.$watch is a string, it defines an expression that is evaluated on your scope. Usually this is a *scope variable*. In your case `order` is not a scope variable but a parameter of the forEach's handler function. You have to use the function way in this case:

```
 $scope.product.orders.forEach(function (order) {
    $scope.$watch(function () {
       return order.details.items.length;
    }, function (n, o) {
       if (n !== o) {
          //do something
        }
     });
  }, true);
```

Comment: works great, thanks. I had not used a watch on a function yet.

Answer (score 2):

For a collection object/array, you should use [`$scope.$watchCollection`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope) instead.

```
$scope.$watchCollection('order.details.items', function (collection) {
    // fires when collection changed, whenever it's length changed or item(s) changed.
})
```